# In velocity report script ,how to find if the user name is already present?

Tags: scripting, velocity

In a for loop, the variable $dispNames gets updated with user first name and last name.

```
set( $dispNames = $dispNames + $user.firstName + " " + $user.lastName + ", ")
```

How do I check if that user already exists in the string and ignore adding to this variable?

Answer (score 1):

The good practice here would rather be to ensure that there are no duplicates in the Java collection you are iterating over, or to remove duplicates by putting those names in a Set on the Java side.

But if this solution is inaccessible in your environment, you can try:

```
#set ($seenUsers = {})
#foreach ($user in $myUsersCollection)
  #set ($fullName = "$user.firstName $user.lastName")
  #if (!$seenUsers.containsKey($fullName))
    #set ($junk = $seenUsers.put($fullName, 1))
    #if ($dispNames.length() > 0)
      #set ($dispNames = "$dispNames,")
    #end
    #set ($dispNames = "$dispNames, $fullName")
  #end
#end
```

This solution uses a map to remember whether a specific user has already been seen. Also, it avoids adding a coma after the last name.

You will also notice that the correct way to concatenate strings in Velocity is to format bigger strings with existing references, not to use the + operator which is dedicated to numerical additions.